# enable / disable all sound effects by clicking on div - javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, switch-statement, effects

I'm building a website in Wordpress and I am using divs and mouse events (onmouseover, onmouseenter and onclick) for different elements on different pages.

I've put audios and scripts in footer:

```
<audio id="ef1"><source src="url"/></audio>
<script type="text/javascript">var ef1 = document.getElementById("ef1"); ef1.volume='0.4';</script>
```

which gets called inside of any div on any page I want with:

```
onmouseenter="ef1.play();"
```

I also have effects for loading certain pages. So not every audio is in footer.

Now the thing is how can I handle all of these audios together - enable / disable all of them with clicking on one single element (div)?

Having a volume slider also won't hurt, but for me enable / disable functionality would be more than enough.

*edit*: I need this to be a switching functionality as onclick event inside a div. all I know for now is to put:

```
onclick="ef1.volume='0'; ef2.volume='0'; etc"
```

problem with this (beside having a lot of audios) is that volumes gets back to normal after refresh or opening other page.

*edit2*: is this what I'm asking even possible? maybe this onclick event should somehow "memorize" ip address, or simply leave cookies? I have no idea how to achieve this (total beginner)...

Answer (score 1):

If you want *all* `<audio>` turned off, you can get them using `document.getElementsByTagName('audio')`. It returns an array (`NodeList` actually) which contains references to all your `<audio>` on the page. You can loop through this array and do something, like call `pause()` on each.

```
var audioElements = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
for(var i = 0; i < audioElements.length; ++i){
  audioElements[i].pause();
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping. however, I don't know what to do with this (I am totally new in this field). I need this to be a switching functionality as onclick event inside a div. all I know for now is to put onclick="ef1.volume='0'; ef2.volume='0'; etc" problem with this (beside having a lot of audios) is that volumes gets back to normal after refresh or opening other page.

Comment: Hey Joseph, I've got back to this problem after a long time. I've tried to implement your code ( $('#allsounds').click(function () {
var audioElements = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
for(var i = 0; i < audioElements.length; ++i){
  audioElements[i].pause();
}
}); ) and it doesn't work. If you are interested, I've posted a more specific question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004393/disable-enable-all-wav-sounds-with-a-click-on-the-div-write-a-cookie-jquer

Comment: It will not work with new Audio()